# Python, Why are only certain attributes of a class instance in a queue available to call in another class?

Tags: python, class, queue

Newbie here.  Trying to edit an API example to do what I need it to do.  Making some progress, but hung up on this issue.

have the following class:

```
class User:
   def __init__(self, emailAddress, emailId, listId, campaignId, fName, lName,gender,birthDate,city,state,country,zip):
    parts = emailAddress.split('@')
    if len(parts) != 2:
        raise Exception("Invalid email address: %s" % emailAddress)

    self.emailAddress = emailAddress.lower()
    self.emailMd5     = hashlib.md5(emailAddress).hexdigest()
    self.domain       = parts[1]
    self.emailId      = emailId
    self.listId       = listId
    self.campaignId   = campaignId
    self.fName        = fName
    self.lName        = lName
    self.gender       = gender
    self.birthDate    = birthDate
    self.city         = city
    self.state        = state
    self.country      = country
    self.zip          = zip
```

I load the emails to a queue, as follows:

```
    u = User(emailAddress, emailId, listId, campaignId, fName, lName, gender,birthDate,city,state,country,zip)
    users[u.emailMd5] = u

    totalEmails += 1
    if len(users) % batchSize == 0:
        q.put(users, block=True)
        users = {}
if len(users) > 0:
    q.put(users, block=True)
for i in xrange(numThreads):
    q.put("done")
```

and where I'm having problems:

```
def buildXmlRequest(self, users):
    emailRecords = []

    for user in users:
        emailRecords.append("<email><recipient>%s</recipient><list>%d</list><domain>%s</domain></email><redirect>http://website/?emailId=%d</redirect>" \
                   % (user.emailMd5, self.cfg['list_id'], user.domain))
```

buildXmlRequest gets called like the following:

```
        users = None
        while users == None:
            try:
                users = self.q.get(timeout=1)
            except Queue.Empty:
                pass
        {snip}
        data['request'] = self.buildXmlRequest(users.values())
```

I want to be able to access "user.emailId", so I can do the following:

```
    for user in users:
        emailRecords.append("<email><recipient>%s</recipient><list>%d</list><domain>%s</domain></email><redirect>http://website/?emailId=%d</redirect>" \
                   % (user.emailMd5, self.cfg['list_id'], user.domain, user.emailId))
```

but according to my IDE (PyCharm 3.0 ), only 'user.domain', and 'user.md5' exist.  I don't even understand where/how these attributes were assigned?  There are only two instances of user.domain (and I've shown both in this code).

I've tried modifying

```
    users[u.emailMd5] = u to:

    users[u.emailId] = u
```

Just to see if it shows up in the IDE, and it does not.

Again, very new to python, so might not be using the correct words in regards to 'class instance' etc.

Thank you!

Comment: What type of structure is your "queue"? Is `users` a dictionary?

Comment: Do you actually get an `AttributeError` when accessing e.g. the `user.emailId`, or do they just not appear in the IDE?

Comment: No errors in python, but I think thats do to exception handling.  Also it does not "work" (no email is sent), when I try the above code I *hoped* would work.  When I remove...it does.

Comment: Unless there's a `try` you haven't included, the string formatting would raise an `AttributeError`. Have you tried `print`ing the string before passing it to `emailRecords.append()`?

Comment: hmmm...the print statement worked.  said it exists

Comment: Then I think the problem is in your IDE figuring out the attributes or the object type (tricky with dynamic type!), rather than the code itself.